# How to find method annotated with a specific annotation without a specific argument set?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Example :

I want to have all the instance of :

```
@Test
$MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$);
```

but not

```
@Test( group="wazoo")
$MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bit tricky because of a bug in SSR, but it's possible using a little script.

Search Pattern:

```
@$Annotation$
$MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$);
```

Click `Edit variables...` and edit `Annotation`:
Text/regexp: `Test`
Script text: `__context__.parent.parameterList.attributes.length == 0`